# How to invoke AJAX on Vertical Tabs?

Tags: 7, ajax, forms

My case is simple: When user switches tabs, I want to dynamically fill empty fields in the tab he entered, calculating them from the tab he went from. Like suggesting city by zip code, or address by company name if I have it in database.

Problem is - I can do it on button click or on field's blur, but I'd prefer it to happen on vertical tab switch. Items with `vertical_tabs` type simply does not have `#ajax` property. Is there any neat way around it?

`#states` seemed a solution, but it seems they only support static value set, like:

```
':input[name="foo"]' => array('value' => 'bar'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#states` attributes cannot use to invoke AJAX. See [drupal_process_states](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_process_states/7)

With your question, i think the solution is write an javascript file and `#attached` it to the form you need.

You can bind a click event to `.vertical-tab-button` element (better) or orverride `Drupal.verticalTab.prototype.focus` function (not recommend).

Comment: Could you elaborate why don't you recommend using `Drupal.verticalTab.focus`?

Comment: bad thing about `.vertical-tab-button` is - it does not contain any kind of id I could use. Any idea how to reliably  recognize which one was clicked?

Comment: Because `Drupal.verticalTab` ship from core. We only change core behaviors when we haven't any other solution.

When an `.vertical-tab-button` click, it'll have class `selected`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to override `Drupal.verticalTab.prototype.focus` though @Sang Le Thanh said not to do so.

You can apply the default behaviour with your custom logic which will not break any Drupal core function.

```php
var defaultFocus = Drupal.verticalTab.prototype.focus;
Drupal.verticalTab.prototype.focus = function() {
    // enter your code
    defaultFocus.apply(this);
}
```